# How to check is window disposed or not

Tags: c#, winforms

I use this code for opening window to be sure that only one window will be created:

```
    ticketTypesForm = ticketTypesForm ?? new fTicketTypes();
    ticketTypesForm.Show();
    ticketTypesForm.Activate();
```

But once I close the window I receive the exception:

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'fTicketTypes'.
```

Comment: If your code is trying to access a disposed object, that may be an indication of a logic error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [IsDisposed-Property in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.isdisposed.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the method *Close* you can use *Hide*. 
The method *Hide* does not dispose the instance of the dialog. So you need not check whether it is disposed any more. Just show the dialog which was hidden before.

The only disadvantage of the *Hide* is residing the dialog's resources in the cache memory. But sometimes it is more convenient.